# update dictionary base on time delta of value

Tags: python

I am trying to update a dictionary based on the time delta generated from its value.

This is an example of the dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'6.1.7.1': {'timestamp':('2020-05-26 12:05:08')},
'1.1.1.2': {'timestamp': ('2020-05-26 12:05:08')},
'2.61.5.4': {'timestamp': ('2020-05-25 12:05:08')},}
```

I want to find out if the key value has a timestamp value that exceeds 24hr to delete it, so I have done this:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

today = date.today()
today=today.strftime(format= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
today=pd.to_datetime(today)
print( today)

for k,v in my_dict.items():
    timedelta = v - today
    if timedelta>24:
        my_dict.pop(k, None)
```

but I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-037388a76b67> in <module>
      8 
      9 for k,v in my_dict.items():
---> 10     timedelta = v - today
     11     if timedelta>24:
     12         my_dict.pop(k, None)

pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._Timestamp.__sub__()
TypeError: descriptor '__sub__' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'dict'
```

How can I manipulate the value of the dictionary to do get the timedelta and after eliminate the key and value in the dictionary? Any help will be appreciated since I am not very familiar with dictionaries.

Comment: Have you created a DataFrame from `my_dict`? This isn't a pandas question right?

Comment: well, I added the tag because I was thinking of a way out converting back the dictionary to a df and to the time delta and then convert it back to a dictionary.. but if you consider this is not pandas question, then I should update the tag. Ideally, I want to keep the dictionary being updated.

Comment: Ok i would remove the pandas tag, this can be done without pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then this should works with you

```
# you can define a filter function which return a new dictionary
def my_filter(my_dict):
    # define a new dict
    new_dict = dict({})
    now = datetime.now()
    now=today.strftime(format= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    now=pd.to_datetime(now)
    # loop on the old dictionary
    for (k, v) in my_dict.items():
        # you have to get the 'timestamp' from each value and convert it to datetime
        timedelta = now - pd.to_datetime(v['timestamp'])
        # convert the timedelta to hours and check if it's less than 24 hours to add it to the new dict
        if (timedelta.days*24+timedelta.seconds/3600)<=24:
            new_dict[k] = v
    return new_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your approach with parsing `str` to `datetime` - that's probably what you are looking for (just the `for` loop)

```py
import copy

for k,v in copy.deepcopy(my_dict).items():
    timedelta = pd.to_datetime(v['timestamp']) - today
    if timedelta.days>1:
        my_dict.pop(k, None)
```

I assumed you want to do `if` with condition for over 1 day, or 24h...

Answer (score 0):

In Python you should *never* modify something you're iterating over. You will get: `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` if you are successful at it.

First, we need to change the entries in `my_dict` to actual timestamps:

```
for k,v in my_dict.items(): 
    my_dict[k] = {'timestamp':pd.to_datetime(v['timestamp'])}
```

Then we can do the comparison, and we create a new dictionary instead of trying to modify one as we're iterating over it:

```
new_dict = {k:v for k,v in my_dict.items() 
            if today - v['timestamp'] <= dt.timedelta(hours=24)}
```

You were comparing `today` and the dictionary entry in the wrong order so the value was always negative.